# SOAP to Stream to String

Tags: c#, serialization, soap

I have a SOAP object that I want to capture as a string.  This is what I have now:

```
RateRequest request = new RateRequest();
//Do some stuff to request here

SoapFormatter soapFormat = new SoapFormatter();
using (MemoryStream myStream = new MemoryStream())
{
  soapFormat.Serialize(myStream, request);
  myStream.Position = 0;
  using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myStream))
  {
    string reqString = sr.ReadToEnd();
  }
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?  I don't care that much about the resulting string format - just so it's human readable.  XML is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's pretty much the way to do it.  You could always factor this out to a method which will do this work for you, and then you can just reduce it to a single call where you need it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also do this:

soapFormat.Serialize(myStream, request);
  string xml=System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(myStream.GetBuffer());